# Stop CSS navbar from scaling with position:relative

Tags: css, html, scaling

I'm using a CSS navbar that has drop down menus. I had a problem with scaling on my site, but some helpful users here helped me fix it. The solution they gave me was to change the position attribute to absolute.
This works fine for text boxes and images, but changing the navbar code to absolute breaks it and makes some of the buttons go to a second line.
Is there a way to stop this from happening and also stop the navbar from bugging out when the page is resized? Sorry if this is hard to understand. This is my navbar CSS, the HTML is just a list:

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/qN8sm/embedded/result/

```
ul {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Times;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 150;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
li ul { display: none; }
ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 7px solid #CC4D4D;
  padding: 25px 30px 30px 30px;
  background: #333333;
  margin-left: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover { background: #757575; }
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
  float: none;
  font-size: 11px;
}
li:hover a { background: #757575; }
li:hover li a:hover { background: #757575; }
```

Comment: better make this a sample in jsfiddle and createa a link for it.Because your Qus was not cleared.

Answer (score 1):

What you could try is set `min-width:(amount of pixels)px`. This sets the minimum width for an element, but if unless you set a `max-width`, it can upscale.

Comment: this is the only solution you can try .. fix min:width.

Comment: I made a jsFiddle to show how the min-width solution would work: http://jsfiddle.net/q6yXx/ . I wrapped the menu with a `div` and applied the following CSS to it: `min-width:700px;`